# Electrical starting problem

Tags: electrical, starting, audi

Audi 80 92  2.0 . Battery problem? Won't start I tried new battery ,same problem. Jumps easily ,drives. Stop. then try to start won't turn. Alternator checked! ok! Someone suggested solenoid on starter motor? Someone else said it's not this but power drain, so not sure. Should I buy a new starter motor? any help would be good.

**EDIT 1** (from answers):

Thanks for answers.I have considered the terminals they look worn but not corroded .The power drain seems to severe for this to be the problem! After searching forums i found a question quite similar for same car and the distributor seemed to be the source of the problem!What do you think?Could this cause serious starting problem? Thanks

**Edit 2** (from answers):

Mechanic looked and considered the battery itself could be the problem..I purchased the battery suggested when you fill in the online form with the reg number.But not powerfull enough for this car !Seems to be working ok.Starting ok.But a couple of things have stopped working ,door open warning noise and internal light.Could this be a fuse?thanks.

Comment: After you put in the brand new, fully charged battery, having cleaned the terminals of both the battery and the cables, it wouldn't crank over? Did I assume too much?

Answer (score 0):

If it starts with a jump, your starter is fine. Even if it cranks slowly (as opposed to not at all), it's possible that it's just not getting enough speed (due to lack of power to the starter) to actually start.

As @mike65535 suggests, check your battery terminals and connectors for corrosion. If the battery is good, and the alternator is good, then you're looking at a connectivity issue - break in the wiring harness (unlikely), or a bad connection between the battery and the harness, or a bad ground.

Also note that, with a bad alternator, the car would likely not run for very long after it's jumped.

An intermittent ground could also be a factor. When you jump start it, you're effectively tying the grounds of the two vehicles together which could mask a bad ground on your car.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - result was overly corroded battery terminal *connectors*.

The place I was jumping from was in very different condition than the contact with the battery posts, resulting in a very similar scenario (Jumpstarts would work but brand new battery would not).

Went to the autozone and found a replacement battery terminal connector; Luckily on my car, the terminal connector on the cables is bolted on, so I was able to remove it and bolt another one on, and suddenly my issue went away. Cost was roughly $15-20 for the part.